# BEM generator mixin want to match MDL structure

Tags: css, sass, mixins, bem

So I have the following mixins to generate my BEM classes:

```
$es: '__';
$ms: '--';

@function to-string($selector) {
    $selector: inspect($selector); //cast to string
    $selector: str-slice($selector, 2, -2); //remove brackets
    @return $selector;
}

@function contains-modifier($selector) {
    $selector: to-string($selector);
    @if str-index($selector, $ms) {
        @return true;
    } @else {
        @return false;
    }
}

@function get-block($selector) {
    $selector: to-string($selector);
    $modifier-start: str-index($selector, $ms) - 1;
    @return str-slice($selector, 0, $modifier-start);
}

@mixin blck($block) {
    .#{$block} {
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin elem($element) {
    $selector: &;
    @if contains-modifier($selector) {
        $block: get-block($selector);
        @at-root {
            #{$selector} {
                #{$block+$es+$element} {
                    @content;
                }
            }
        }
    } @else {
        @at-root {
            #{$selector+$es+$element} {
                @content;
            }
        }
    }
}

@mixin modf($modifier) {
    @at-root {
      #{&}#{$ms+$modifier} {
            @content;
        }
    }
}

@include blck(block) {
    background: red;
    @include elem(child){
        color: blue;
    };
    @include modf(modifier) {
        background: blue;
        @include elem(child) {
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

Now this actually generates perfect BEM style code but I want to to match the MDL code structure which means I want to more specificity nest my modifiers form this

```
.block
.block--modifer
```

to

```
.bock.block--modifier
```

The reason for this as said before is to match MDL an example of this formatting can be seen here: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/master/src/card/_card.scss

Now I can almost get the desired effect by changing this line:

```
@mixin modf($modifier) {
    @at-root {
      #{&}#{$ms+$modifier} {
            @content;
        }
    }
}
```

To this:

```
@mixin modf($modifier) {
    @at-root {
      #{&}#{&}#{$ms+$modifier} {
            @content;
        }
    }
}
```

But that changes the CSS output from this:

```
.block {
  background: red;
}
.block__child {
  color: blue;
}
.block--modifier {
  background: blue;
}
.block--modifier .block__child {
  color: red;
}
```

To this:

```
.block {
  background: red;
}
.block__child {
  color: blue;
}
.block.block--modifier {
  background: blue;
}
.block.block--modifier .block.block__child {
  color: red;
}
```

Now as you can see this fixes the modifier specificity but breaks the modifier child.

The desired output is as follows:

```
.block.block--modifier .block__child {
  color: red;
}
```

You can see it all in action here: http://codepen.io/crashy/pen/wGWPvr

Comment: Have you stopped to think about whether or not this is a good idea?  You've written so much code here in an effort to save yourself a few keystrokes.  Any solution to your problem is going to be even more verbose.

Comment: @cimmanon Hello yes I have and the reason I want to do this is it stops things like typo's in your children and modifies and it keeps the CSS flat and correctly structured and while it is a whole lot of code for the tiny example given once applied to a framework where there are multiple BEM structured classes I think it will become invaluable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something quick i came up with by forking your pen:

1. Add the #{$selector} in modf mixin.
2. Modify the get-block function so that it returns the actual base class. At first we slice the string up to the point of the modifier (--) and then we check if there are more than one classes in the concatenated string. If there are more than one, we get the first.

Link from codepen:  http://codepen.io/MKallivokas/pen/bpBYEg

```
$es: '__'; // Element
$ms: '--'; // Modifier
$ns: 'ns'; // Name space (Set to null if un-wanted)

@if($ns) {
  $ns: $ns + '-';
}

@function to-string($selector) {
    $selector: inspect($selector); //cast to string
    $selector: str-slice($selector, 2, -2); //remove brackets
    @return $selector;
}

@function contains-modifier($selector) {
    $selector: to-string($selector);
    @if str-index($selector, $ms) {
        @return true;
    } @else {
        @return false;
    }
}

@function get-block($selector) {
    // do what get-block was doing in order to
    // remove the modifier's part from the string
    $selector: to-string($selector);
    $modifier-start: str-index($selector, $ms) - 1;
    $selector: str-slice($selector, 0, $modifier-start);
    // remove the first dot
    $selector: str-slice($selector, 2, str-length($selector));
    // check if there is another dot
    $modifier-start: str-index($selector, '.') - 1;
    @if $modifier-start >= 0 {
      // if there's another dot we slice the string up to that point
      $selector: str-slice($selector, 0, $modifier-start);
    }
    // we insert the dot that we removed to the start
    $selector: str-insert($selector, '.', 1);
    @return $selector;
}

@mixin blck($block) {
  .#{$ns}#{$block} {
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin elem($element) {
    $selector: &;
    @if contains-modifier($selector) {
        $block: get-block($selector);
        @at-root {
            #{$selector} {
                #{$block+$es+$element} {
                    @content;
                }
            }
        }
    } @else {
        @at-root {
            #{$selector+$es+$element} {
                @content;
            }
        }
    }
}

@mixin modf($modifier) {
  $selector: &;
  @at-root {
    #{$selector}#{$selector+$ms+$modifier} {
      @content;
    }
  }
}

@include blck(block) {
    background: red;
    @include elem(child){
        color: blue;
    };
    @include modf(modifier) {
        background: blue;
        @include elem(child) {
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if it suits exactly your needs or covers every case of what you want to do but i hope it helps.